# how to monitor a database table for a specific data?

Tags: javascript, sql-server

I have a database table ,entries are made after a process is executed and completed, like a log table. I want to monitor this table for these process and raise an alert if the entry is not made before specific time. For example if a process is not completed before 3 am there should be an alert mechanism like an email alert or a web page displaying the breach ? What is the best way to achieve this? I just want a logic.

Comment: write a query and schedule it to execute at 3 AM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an insert trigger on the table and based on what exactly field value your are looking for , insert the field value into some temp table. At 3 am, just query this temp table. If value is present it is success. A detailed description of trigger for sale server can be found here 
https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Simple-Insert-Update-and-Delete-Triggers-in-SQL-Server-with-example.aspx

You can query customer logs for field customer id